# Array cast as long pointer?

Tags: c

```
long long a64[10];
long k32, *p32;
p32 = ((long *) &a64[k32]) + 1;
```

I don't understand the last line. What is p32 pointing to exactly?

Comment: Why is the question being down voted though?

Answer (score 1):

The whole thing gets a pointer to the second half of the `k32`nd element in the array.

The array element is a `long long`. Half of a `long long` is a `long`. The second half is found by casting the `long long *` pointer to a `long *` and then incrementing by 1. That gives you a pointer to the second half.

```
           a64[k32]       // the k32'nd element of the array     type: long long
          &a64[k32]       // address of the k32'nd element       type: long long *
 (long *) &a64[k32]       // that address re-cast to long *      type: long *
((long *) &a64[k32] + 1)  // the second half of the k32'nd item  type: long *
```

This is not completely portable. It would be safer to use `int32_t` and `int64_t` instead of `long` and `long long`. It also assumes a particular endianness.

Comment: k32 isn't set, so the whole thing is undefined behavior. "Half of a long long is a long" -- not necessarily. http://www.unix.org/version2/whatsnew/lp64_wp.html